# react-hook-form How can I pass field value to a parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I want to get the value of a field inside a react-hook-form component and print it outside the form.
The value should be updated onChange. is there a way to use the useWatch outside the form component?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm, useWatch } from "react-hook-form";

import "./styles.css";

function Form() {
  const { register, control, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => console.log("data", data))}>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input ref={register} name="name" />
        <p>{useWatch({ control, name: "name" })}</p>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>The Value of the input should goes here</h1>
      <Form />
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Edit code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v6-usewatch-forked-oym7l?file=/src/index.js:0-1544)

Comment: Your desired `JSX` would be like this: `<Form /><WatchedField/>` or you want to have `<WatchedField/>` inside `Form` but calling `useWatch` in the `WatchedField` body rather than `From` ?

Answer (score 9):

Put `useForm()` in your parent component, then pass it as props to your child component

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm, useWatch } from "react-hook-form";

import "./styles.css";

function Form({ form }) {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = form;
  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => console.log("data", data))}>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input ref={register} name="name" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
function App() {
  const form = useForm();
  const { control } = form
  const name = useWatch({ control, name: "name" })
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      <Form form={form} />
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Or, you can also make use of `useFormContext()` inside your child component, without passing any props. The `useFormContext()` hook will get context from parent or nearest ancestor's `useForm()`.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm, useWatch, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

import "./styles.css";

function Form() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useFormContext();
  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => console.log("data", data))}>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input ref={register} name="name" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
function App() {
  const { control } = useForm();
  const name = useWatch({ control, name: "name" })
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      <Form />
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: I'm following either of your examples, but I wonder- is it necessary to handleSubmit in the child? I have many children in one form so I think I should have one submit button in the parent. That's what I'm trying at the moment but getting undefined data on submit. And what about using a controller in the child?